# Filtering out old dates using advances filter in excel

Tags: excel, filter, advanced-filter

The example in [office documentation for advanced filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b) has a table like this (I added `Date` column):

```
Type       Salesperson   Sales  Date
Beverages  Suyama        $5122  10/1/2018
Meat       Davolio       $450   11/5/2018
produce    Buchanan      $6328  3/8/2019
Produce    Davolio       $6544  3/1/2019
```

I would like to see only lines that have dates from the past 14 days. Based on the manual, advanced filter can be something like this:

```
Date
>=2/25/2019
```

But that is only good for today. I tried using

```
Date
>=now()-14
```

which doesn't work. Is there a way to use a function in the advanced filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that doesn't need helper column. This is my filter:

```
Date
=">"&TEXT(NOW()-14,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Today, this evaluates to:

```
Date
>02/28/2019
```

So, formulas can't be part of text as I had originally tried. But the field can be any formula that evaluates to a string containing a valid filter.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to introduce a "helper column" starting in E2 with the formula `=D2>NOW()-14` (and E3, E4,... referring to D3, D4,...) - then you can filter in your helper column just with boolean value.